# Jquery .load and subdomains

Tags: jquery, load

I am trying to load a file (http://domain.com/v2/inc/review.php) from a subdomain (http://resort.domain.com) using jquery. Although I use the full location it refuses to load.
Does anyone know how to get it to work?

```
$("#resort").load("http://domain.com/v2/inc/review.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

To make things short. You can't load remote domain content with ajax. This a restriction applied by all browsers and is called the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So trying to load data from a different subdomain is already a violation of the same origin policy.

The only thing you can do to load data from a different domain is use json

[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

---

@Matt's comment:

I was indeed thinking about JSONP. Which is exactly what jQuery getJson uses if the url is on a remote server

From the documentation:

> If the specified URL is on a remote
>   server, the request is treated as
>   `JSONP` instead. See the discussion of
>   the jsonp data type in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) for
>   more details.

Comment: Not technically correct. Making an AJAX call and returning JSON will still get affected. Perhaps you're thinking of JSONP?

Comment: Yes I meant JSONP see expanded answer

Answer (score 0):

In the Javascript for the page on http://resort.domain.com, do...

```
document.domain = "domain.com";
```

Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are running in to the security restriction that browsers have with doing an ajax request from a different domain.  One option is to proxy your request through your current domain.  Something like [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using document.domain is the most compatible method with the most flexibility.

document.domain = "domain.com";

Here is a good summary presentation of different cross-domain techniques:
http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier

But it is of utter importance that no one else can setup subdomains on that domain, because if they can, they can use it for fishing data.